# Whether or not a certain function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $f:X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be measurable, and let $u_n:X\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ be measurable for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to know if $\left( 1 + \frac{f}{u_n}\right)^{u_n}$ is measurable.

I need this step to prove the convergence of a certain sequence of integrals.

I know that $\left( 1 + \frac{f}{u_n}\right)$ is measurable since $u_n$ is never zero. I just don't know how to show it is measurable when I raise it to $u_n$.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What does $x^y$ actually mean? Here is one definition: $e^{ylog(x)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Rather than looking at the function as
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{f}{u_n}\right)^{u_n},
$$
how about 
$$
\exp \left( u_n \log \left( 1 + \frac{f}{u_n} \right)\right)?
$$

Comment: Yes thanks for your help, I believe I have figured it out from this hint and the above comment from Tim

Comment: So you're using that the composition and multiplication of measurable functions is measurable?